# Inverse of matrix with nonnegative entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am interested in matrices with the property that both $A$ and $A^{-1}$ have nonnegative entries.  The only such matrices I could construct were diagonal matrices, and my question is whether these are the only such examples.

What I can say about such matrices is that they must preserve the quadrant
$$
Q^+ = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n \mid x_i \geq 0 \}.
$$
That is, $x\in Q^+$ if and only if $Ax\in Q^+$.  This seems rather unlikely unless $A$ preserves the axes, that is, unless $A$ is diagonal.  But I can't seem to turn this into a proof.

**EDIT**

Cameron Buie made the nice observation that permutation matrices also work.
So I wonder: are there any examples with more than $n$ nonzero entries?  What about 2x2 examples with at least 3 nonzero entries?

Comment: Well, any permutation matrix should work (that is, any matrix such that each row and each column has exactly one $1$ as an entry, and has $0$ for all other entries).

Comment: Ah, beautiful.  Nice catch!  And then, I suppose matrices that are nonnegative along a permutation also work.  Perhaps there's more?

Comment: I'm sure there are more. That was just a class of examples off the top of my head.

Comment: @Cameron: actually there aren't!

Comment: @Qiaochu: You give me too much credit! I hadn't even processed that the OP was talking about weighted permutation matrices. I'd actually sat down to prove that any such matrix would have to send positive axes to positive axes, second-guessed myself, and then realized permutation matrices would provide another example, at least. Nice to know that my first instinct was right! Now I want to try to prove it. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These can be classified using the [Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) as follows. The conclusion is that Cameron Buie's examples, the weighted permutation matrices, actually exhaust all examples!

Let $A$ be a square matrix with nonnegative entries. We'll interpret it as the weighted adjacency matrix of a [weighted directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Weighted_graph) $G$, where if the weight is $0$ there is no edge. Say that $A$ is **irreducible** if this graph is [strongly connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component), meaning that every vertex can be reached from every other vertex. Any such $A$ can be conjugated by a permutation (note that this preserves the desired property) into a block sum of irreducible blocks corresponding to the strongly connected components of the corresponding weighted graph, and $A$ has the property that $A^{-1}$ has nonnegative entries iff each of its irreducible blocks does. Hence from now on, we'll assume WLOG that $A$ is irreducible.

The Perron-Frobenius theorem asserts that if $A$ is irreducible then, among other things,

- It has eigenvalue $r = \rho(A)$, the [spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) of $A$ (the largest absolute value of an eigenvalue).
- $r$ has an eigenvector $v_r$ all of whose entries are positive reals.
- The only positive eigenvectors are those with eigenvalue $r$.

This means it's very hard for $A^{-1}$ to also have nonnegative entries, because $A^{-1}$ still has a positive eigenvector $v_r$ but it's now associated to the eigenvalue which is smallest in absolute value rather than largest. Note also that if $A^{-1}$ is reducible then taking inverses again implies that $A$ is reducible, so if $A$ is irreducible then so is $A^{-1}$, so if $A^{-1}$ has nonnegative entries the Perron-Frobenius theorem also applies to it.

The conclusion is that all of the eigenvalues of $A$ must be the same in absolute value. The Perron-Frobenius theorem says even more now. Define the **period** $h$ of $A$ to be the gcd of the lengths of all closed directed paths on $G$. For example, if $G$ is a weighted $n$-cycle this period is $n$.

- $A$ has exactly $h$ eigenvalues of absolute value $r$.
- $A$ can be conjugated by a permutation into an $h \times h$ block matrix whose blocks describe an $h$-cycle.

See the Wikipedia article for the precise statement; the upshot is that in this case we must have $h = n$ because every eigenvalue has absolute value $r$, and the conclusion is that $A$ is, up to conjugation by permutations, a weighted cycle. Blocks of these give weighted permutations and that's all we get.

Comment: Very cool!  Thanks for the answer, I hadn't seen the Perron-Frobenius theorem before.

Answer (score 7):

Of course, il maestro @Qiaochu Yuan is right; and, of course, he knows that there exists an elementary proof !

Let $A=[a_{p,q}],A^{-1}=[b_{p,q}]$. We consider the $i^{th}$ row of the matrix $A$ and we assume that there are $j\not= k$ s.t. $a_{i,j},a_{i,k}\not= 0$. Then $AA^{-1}=I$ implies that, for every $p\not= i$, $b_{j,p}=b_{k,p}=0$. Thus, the rows $j,k$ of $B$ are proportional and $B$ is not invertible, that is contradictory. Using $A^{-1}A=I$, we show the same result for the columns of $A$ and we are done.

Comment: Ha! Wow. Yeah, maybe I should've tried that first.

Comment: What does this prove? That the weighted permutation matrices are the desired matrices,  or that there are no other solutions?

Comment: @GFauxPas , the set of solutions is the set of all weighted permutation matrices.